# Custom validation errors on nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Parent
  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end
class Child
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Using a nested object form, I need to add some extra validations to the child model. These are not always run on Child, so I cannot put them in a `validate` method in Child. It seems sensible to do the checking in a validate method in Parent, but I'm having trouble adding error messages correctly.

This does work:

```
class Parent
...
def validate
  errors[ :"child.fieldname" ] = "Don't be blank!"
end
```

But we lose nice things like I18n and CSS highlighting on the error field.

This doesn't work:

```
def validate
  errors.add :"child.fieldname", :blank
end
```

Comment: My initial thinking is to always have the child validations on the child model. Why not do that?

Comment: Different validations for different situations. In my particular case, some child models are created without a parent, and those have looser validations than those created through parents.

Comment: So make them conditional on the presence of a parent. You should still keep them in the child model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep them in the child model since that's the one validated, however, you can set conditionals with `if:` and `unless:`

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :card_number, presence: true, if: :paid_with_card?

  def paid_with_card?
    payment_type == "card"
  end
end
```

You can do several variations on this, read more in the rails documentation http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

I guess you could add an attribute, `created_by` to child, and make Child select which validations to use depending on that one. You can do that like they do in this answer: [Rails how to set a temporary variable that's not a database field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697041/rails-how-to-set-a-temporary-variable-thats-not-a-database-field)