# Rails how to set a temporary variable that's not a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

For my app, I have different signup entry points that validate things differently.

So in the main signup, nothing is required except for the email and password field. In an alternative signup field, many more are required. So in the user model I have

```
validate_presence_of :blah, :lah, :foo, :bah, :if => :flag_detected

def flag_detected
  !self.flag.nil?
end
```

I want to set that flag through the controller. However that flag isn't a database field. I'm just wondering if this is achievable in Rails or there is something wrong with the way that I am thinking about this? If so, what's the best way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: "instance variables" (exposed via accessors -- e.g. `attr` -- if needed). It is up for debate if it's "good practice" to do so in a Model, precisely because they are *not* part of the *persisted* model. However, in a Controller, why not?

Comment: I only need it to be a temporary variable for that save called from the controller. When I set @user.flag = true in the controller, I don't actually see it in the model though.

Comment: So I need to define an attr_accessor to it? What if I already have attr_protected, is there anyway around that then?

Comment: you could always write your own "action" method and not use properties: `theModel.flag_for_followup` (for instance, or whatever is appropriate). Or, perhaps create a separate object (or only use variables in the Controller) and not add non-persisted properties to the model..

Comment: Hi @pst, is it possible if you can elaborate a bit on that? Do you mean to create my own save method so that I can pass that variable through?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

What you need is `attr_accessor`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :flag
  attr_accessible :flag # if you have used attr_accessible or attr_protected else where and you are going to set this field during mass-assignment. If you are going to do user.flag = true in your controller's action, then no need this line
end
```

basically `attr_accessor :flag` create the `user.flag` and `user.flag = ...` methods for your model.

and `attr_accessible` is for mass-assignment protection.

Comment: Doh! not for Rails 4 http://easyactiverecord.com/blog/2014/04/01/rails4-strong-parameters-and-the-attr-accessible-macro/

Comment: I find it easiest to just use a class variable @flag for this matter ..

Answer (score 3):

Following up on the best practice debate:

Create a method that does what you want.  I.e. save_with_additional_validation. This is much more clear and self-documenting code and works the same way. Just call this method instead of save()

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to define setter method

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :flag

   def flag=(boolean)
     boolean
   end
 end
```

Comment: Just tried that, along with attr_accessible too, but it's still not working.