# Musician expected, got String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, controller, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to create a new User, but User has_one Musician, and Musician belongs_to User. Before create this relation, my create was working, but now I'm receiving the error:

Musician expected, got String

But I don't know why this is happening, I guess is something with my user_id, like this topic [Country expected, got String error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5716412/country-expected-got-string-error) but I'm not sure, and don't know how to fix it, here is my User controller

```
def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    if params[:user].musician
      @user.musico = Musician.New

    else
      @user.estudio = Studio.new 
    end

    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
       flash[:success] = "Welcome!!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And here is the submit

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"VjOUW75ocw8rw/rEqa076x9N/Oa/5AjMxBOmRGAaDAM=",
 "user"=>{
 "firstName"=>"Eduardo",
 "lastName"=>"Almeida",
 "email"=>"eduardo@teste.com.br",
 "city"=>"Mogi",
 "password"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "musician"=>"true"},
 "commit"=>"Criar Conta"}
```

EDIT: The form

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/erros' %>
    <%= f.label :firstName, "Nome" %>
    <%= f.text_field :firstName%><br/>      
    <%= f.label :lastName, "Sobrenome" %>
    <%= f.text_field :lastName%><br/>
    <%= f.label :email, "Email"%>
    <%= f.text_field :email%><br/>
    <%= f.label :city, "Cidade"%>
    <%= f.text_field :cidade%><br/>
    <%= f.label :password, "Senha"%>
    <%= f.password_field :password%><br/>
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirme a senha"%>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation%><br/>
    <%= f.hidden_field :newMusico, :value => true%>
    <%= f.submit "Criar Conta", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Musician expected, got guitarist  :-)  :-)  ?

Comment: `Musician.New` is a problem. Case matters in a case-sensitive language. It's also a slightly puzzling relationship. It looks like you're trying to set a flag to true/false, indicating whether a user is a musician, which makes more sense than a user *having* a musician.

Comment: That happens because by default all users are musicians, but if an Admin create an user, the user is a Studio, and the models have different columns. Actually a user <i>is</i> a musician (or studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `User` with the parameters from your request. This includes a `musician` parameter. This is equivalent to doing:

```
u = User.new
u.musician = "true"
```

The user instance is expecting a `Musician` instance because of your `has_one :musician` association.

To fix you could rename the parameter you use to indicate whether a musician or a studio should be added to your new user, e.g. `new_musician`

I think you'll then hit a problem with testing `params[:user].new_musician`. `params[:user]` is a Hash so you need to access it like `params[:user][:musician]`. Also, it is going to have a string value `"true"` or `"false"` so you'll need to check:

```
if params[:user][:new_musician] == "true"
```

Comment: I got your point, but I didn't understood how can I set a boolean in the form (it will be a hidden field) to select between create a Musician or a Studio, and them associate the User with its model.I will edit my question to place show the form

Comment: If I take that info from the form It works, but how can I know which type of user is being created without create a new column ?

Comment: If I just add an attr_accessible :newMusician I got the error: unknown attribute: newMusician

Comment: You don't need to make it an attribute on the `User` class as all you are doing is checking it in the controller and creating a different associated object as a result. If you add `f.hidden_field :newMusico, :value => false` to your new studio you will be able to tell the difference between them.

Comment: Yout answer and this other question solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9697041/rails-how-to-set-a-temporary-variable-thats-not-a-database-field